# mysql select then update / joining?

Tags: mysql, select

I have been reading for a few hours but my learning curve just isn't helping! I'm trying to find a few rows by doing a select statement, then when it matches, I need to grab the result and pair it up with another table then do an update. Somehow, from what I'm reading and applying, it's not helping me much.

Please kindly help me as I can't comprehend these things without seeing and applying what I'm doing... Here is my code:

```
select code as codea from routes where r1=1 (update plans set active=1 where code=codea) limit 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update with `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE plans p 
INNER JOIN routes r ON p.code = r.codea
SET p.active = 1 
WHERE r.r1 = 1
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: thanks for your help. this seems to work however I can't set a limit for some reason, it's telling me that incorrect usage of update.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
update plans set
active = 1 
where code = (select code as codea
              from routes
              where r1=1)
```